# chrome extension can not get header with onHeadersReceived

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to read the response header of a website with a chrome extension but I am not able to retrieve the header in the extension. I guess something is preventing the background script to access the header and I would love to know what, and if it is possible to disable this.

**manifest.json**

```
"permissions": [
  "webRequest",
  "webRequestBlocking",
  "*://*/"
],
"background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"],
  "persistent": true
},
```

**background.js**

```
function requestProcessor(details) {
    alert(details.url+' => '+JSON.stringify(details.responseHeaders));
    return {responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders};
}
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(requestProcessor, {
    urls: ["*://*/*"],
    types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]
}, ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]);
```

**response header** of the website that I got with the dev tools

```
cache-control:no-cache
content-encoding:gzip
content-security-policy: ...
content-type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
date:Sun, 23 Oct 2016 21:09:52 GMT
last-modified:Tue, 18 Oct 2016 21:56:14 GMT
pragma:no-cache
server:...
status:200
strict-transport-security:max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains; preload
vary:Accept-Encoding, User-Agent, Accept-Language
via:HTTP/1.1 169.111.111.111:443 (/ 66.111.111.111)
x-connected-to:169.111.111.111
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-fb-ip-type:allowed
x-frame-options:DENY
```

Comment: Match pattern in manifest lacks path component, should be `"*://*/*"`

Comment: I tried it but it makes not difference

Comment: Have you tried deleting `types: ["main_frame", "sub_frame"]` ?

Comment: Yes I did and I got every image and other linked resource except for the main page

Comment: Actually the page I am trying to get is https://web.whatsapp.com/ but I was reluctant to mention it at first since it might trigger a lot of other questions. I am trying to create a media player for it (https://github.com/select/whatsapp-web-media-player) which works (on other pages fully) but is not able to show the YouTube videos on whatsapp due to content restrictions.